# Can't mass-assign protected attributes in Rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Migration

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :password_digest

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :password_digest
  validates :name, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true
  has_secure_password
end
```

User's registration _form

```
.main_form
  = form_for @user do |f|

    %div
      = f.label :name
      = f.text_field :name, :size=>40

    %div
      = f.label :password, "Password"
      = f.password_field :password

    %div
      = f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation"
      = f.password_field :password_field

    %div
      = f.submit 'Create user'
```

When I try to register a new user it throws an exception

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in UsersController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: password, password_field
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add these two fields to your `has_accessible` list. Rails does not only protect database fields from mass assignment but all fields like these 'virtual' fields too.

In User model (instead of your `attr_accesible` line):

```
attr_accessible :name, :password_field, :password
```

Also, `password_digest` should not be available to modify in any case, that is a calculated field not user input.

Comment: What file should I add them to?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, it is needed to be in the `User` model. Replace your `attr_accesible` line with mine, it should work.